# D3 samples in a Microsoft Stack

Tags: javascript, asp.net, file-io, d3.js

We're trying to get familiar with D3 (http://d3js.org/), in particular samples such as http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3306362 and http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590. It seems all these samples use local file IO to load geolocation info. The following code snippets are common:

```
queue()
.defer(d3.json, "/mbostock/raw/4090846/us.json")
.defer(d3.tsv, "unemployment.tsv")
.await(ready)
```

while other samples often use this signature to load data:

```
d3.json("someJSONFile.json", function(error, uk) {
console.log(uk);
});
```

We've created several local html files to test out the samples, but we're running into security issues. It's apparent the script is accessing a local file, which is really giving us problems in a Microsoft stack (Apple or Linux isn't an option at this time, though we have tried Chrome, with no success). How can we enable the html file or refactor the script to have access to the local files?

Comment: Are you getting messages like "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/someJSONfile.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP." ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to host the files through a web server since web browsers restrict what types of files can be accessed locally. The simplest way to do this on a windows machine:

1. Install [python](http://www.python.org/getit/)
2. Navigate to the directory holding your example with `cmd.exe`. Holding down shift, right clicking on the folder with the example and selecting `Open Command Window Here` is the easiest way to do this.
3. On the command prompt, enter `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`, or `python -m http.server 8000`, on newer versions to start a web server.
4. Open a web browser (I would really suggest chrome, the dev tools are way ahead of ff and ie), go to `127.0.0.1:8000`. The example should show up.

Comment: Python seems to be the development environment of choice with D3 examples. I was hoping there was another way, but it's apparent the Python route allows easy access to local files. For learning purposes this may be the easiest method until we get some web services up and running on a full blown ASP.net web site.

Comment: If you're more familiar with the windows stack, it might be easier to just use an IIS site (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323972). The python route is pretty simple though, and shouldn't take more than 15 min to get going.