# how to import data into d3js correctly

Tags: d3.js, data-import

I get pretty excited about the D3.js studying and presentation. And I get stuck on the data importing part. I've tried one month now, and couldn't find a solution for it.

If the data is simply pasted in the code, the scripts works perfectly fine. But once I tried to import the data from outside the script. The webpage won't show anything.

Can someone be kind enough to give me a hand?

Here are my scripts and data:

Working version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
    <charset=utf-8">
    <title>Successful Data Comination In Bar Chart</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>

    var dataset = [{"name":"AAA", "age":10},{"name":"BBB", "age":20},{"name":"CCC", "age":30}];

    var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 500)
            .attr("height", 500);

    canvas.selectAll("rect")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("width", function (d) { return d.age*10; })
            .attr("height", 48)
            .attr("y", function (d,i) { return i*50; })
            .attr("fill", "gray");

    canvas.selectAll("text")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()  
            .append("text")
            .attr("fill", "white")
            .attr("x", 2)
            .attr("y", function (d,i) { return i*50 +27; })
            .text(function (d) { return d.name + " "  + d.age; }); 

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Not working version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
    <charset=utf-8">
    <title>Testing Pie Chart</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>

    var dataset = [];

    d3.json("mydata.json", function(data) {

        dataset = data;

        var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 500)
            .attr("height", 500);



        canvas.selectAll("rect")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("width", function (d) { return d.age*10; })
                .attr("height", 48)
                .attr("y", function (d,i) { return i*50; })
                .attr("fill", "gray");

        canvas.selectAll("text")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()  
                .append("text")
                .attr("fill", "white")
                .attr("x", 2)
                .attr("y", function (d,i) { return i*50 +27; })
                .text(function (d) { return d.name + " "  + d.age; }); 
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The json data named "mydata.json" is like:

```
[
    {"name": "AAA", "age": 10},
    {"name": "BBB", "age": 20},
    {"name": "CCC", "age": 30}
]
```

I am new to Stackoverflow, and trying to edit it as I want, but not perfect. Please feel free to let me know if you get confused about the codes. I will explain, cause I really want to solve this. Thanks a lot!

Thanks for tipping me off! Looking forward to your reply keenly!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17077931/d3-samples-in-a-microsoft-stack?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Thanks Adam. So is it a server/web browser problem? Because the web browser can not read the local data file(in my case, the mydata.json file)?

Comment: roippi's answer is correct; the above link has windows specific instructions that shouldn't be too tricky to follow.

Comment: Hi Adam, I tried your way in the link above, and unluckily for the result. In the cmd window, it says

C:\Python27\python.exe: No module named Simple
Can someone shed some light on this feedback?

I am really naive and new to the server, so please forgive my dumb question, if it bothers you.

Thanks! And looking forward to your help!

Comment: No, I had a typo! "python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000" w/ no space. Glad you got it to work, have fun w/ d3!

Comment: LOL that's alright. Thanks, @AdamPearce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a security feature in browsers known as the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).  You can view this in action by firing up your browser-of-choice's dev tools and seeing what happens when it tries to fetch your JSON file.

There are various methods to work around this.  If you have access to web hosting, throw it up there.  Otherwise, choose a method to run a lightweight server locally.  The simplest one that people are routinely told is to serve an `index.html` file in python:

```
#(in v2.x)
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000

#(in v3.x)
python -m http.server 8000
```

then browsing to localhost:8000.  This is explained in slightly more detail on the [d3 wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki).  For more in-depth explanations and whatnot, I recommend [some reading](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch04.html#_setting_up_a_web_server).

Comment: Thanks Roippi. Funny enough, I read the interactive data visualization as well. But skip the setting up part, because at that time, I thought that it was more of a production side story. Learned a lesson :) I will read that part more carefully, and try to adjust the setting. I am stuck with Microsoft Windows. So I guess that it will take a while to fix the problem. But still, I am very happy that I can get your help so quickly! Thanks again!

Comment: Installing python on windows is quick and painless, don't let that dissuade you.

Comment: I will try python first. Thanks Roippi!

Comment: Just did. Got used to the thumbs up stuff... :)

Comment: I'd recommend xampp as probably the most painless server for running a standalone. It runs a tomcat instance from localhost, and you don't have to worry about any server setup.

Comment: @ckersch, thanks for your help! I tried it. I installed xampp for my windows system. In XAMPP control panel, I started Tomcat only. I also moved all my web app document in "C:\xampp\htdocs". When I use web browser to open the following link: "http://localhost:8080/WebDesignApp/D3Test/Interactive_Data_Visualization_for_the_Web.html", it shows the following message on the web browser:

Comment: "HTTP Status 404 -/WebDesignApp/D3Test/Interactive_Data_Visualization_for_the_Web.html
type Status report
message /WebDesignApp/D3Test/Interactive_Data_Visualization_for_the_Web.html
description The requested resource is not available."
 Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ckersch, great news! I worked it out. I just did what roippi told me again. This time it works! I am not sure why it didn't earlier. Just feel happy now. Thanks again.