# JSON call error with d3js

Tags: json, d3.js

I'm trying to replicate [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/rtaW4mBcUN9bepq8p4Bo?p=preview) of a bar chart that transitions in d3js. However, when I input my data into the .json file I get the error "Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined" so I'm pretty sure I'm calling the .json file incorrectly. I have correctly changed the names of my variables, which are dates instead of text, so maybe that's messing something up:

Here's my .json file:

```
[{"network":"ABC","2002":9860,"2003":10596,"2004":9989,"2005":12217,"2006":12281,"2007":11913,"2008":12265,"2009":11050,"2010":9595,"2011":9871,"2012":8339},
{"network":"AZA","2002":0,"2003":0,"2004":0,"2005":0,"2006":213,"2007":0,"2008":0,"2009":201,"2010":236,"2011":212,"2012":0},
{"network":"CBS","2002":13959,"2003":13856,"2004":13581,"2005":12843,"2006":13019,"2007":11726,"2008":11274,"2009":11812,"2010":12538,"2011":12284,"2012":10690}]
```

And how I've tried to call it:

```
var json 

d3.json("data.json", function(error, result){
  json = result;
  var data = [];
        json.forEach(function(d){
            data.push({variable: +d['2002'], network: d['network']});
         });
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.network; }));
  y.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.variable; }), d3.max(data, function(d) {      return d.variable; })]);
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17077931/d3-samples-in-a-microsoft-stack?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: The error message suggests that `json` is undefined. This will happen if there was an error retrieving the file. Did you check what `error` contains?

Comment: Try using Firebug to debug and find out what's in json; it looks like it didn't load what you expect.  Maybe your path is wrong?

Comment: I'm running a simple server so it's not a cross origin error, chrome inspector just says: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined
(anonymous function) t u

Answer (score 0):

Your D3js code does not have any error.May be the json file is unreachable(as per the code the json file should reside in same folder of the HTML file).
   You can use "console.log(json);" just after the line "json = result;" if the data is read from the file u will find it in console of "FireBug" or "Developer tools"(in chrome)

Answer (score 0):

You might have an older version of D3 than in the example. I ran into the same problem and found that my version of D3 did not have an error parameter on the json function so the first parameter passed (the error, which was null) was expected to be the JSON string. So the 2 solutions I found are:

(1) Switch the parameters to have the JSON first:

```
d3.json("data.json", function(result, error){ ...
```

or just remove the error parameter altogether.

(2) Update to d3.v3.js.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reporting this question ,
Your error is because of your json file is unreachable.

Comment: like your data.json is unreachable file.please put it in your base code folder